# Solve $\log_{(-x^2-6x)/10}(\sin 3x+\sin x)= \log_{(-x^2-6x)/10}(\sin 2x).$

Tags: trigonometry

Question : Solve
$$\log_{(-x^2-6x)/10}(\sin 3x+\sin x)=
\log_{(-x^2-6x)/10}(\sin 2x).$$

My try : [image]

I am unable to proceed from here

Comment: The question is very hard to read, since it is extremly large and has the wrong orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically finished and found the solution. Indeed:
$$\cos x=\frac12 \Rightarrow x=\pm\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi m,m\in \mathbb Z;\\
-6<x<0 \Rightarrow -6<\pm\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi m<0\\
\sin 2x>0 \Rightarrow 2\sin x\cos x>0 \Rightarrow \sin x>0 \Rightarrow \\
0+2\pi n<x<\pi+2\pi n,n\in \mathbb Z.$$
Hence:
$$\begin{cases}-6<\pm\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi m<0\\2\pi n<x<\pi+2\pi n\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}-6<-\frac{\pi}{3};\frac{\pi}{3}-2\pi<0\\ -2\pi<\frac{\pi}{3}-2\pi<\pi-2\pi\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
x=\frac{\pi}{3}-2\pi=-\frac{5\pi}{3}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The base of the logarithms is the same, so you get
$$
\begin{cases}
\sin3x+\sin x=\sin2x \\[4px]
\sin2x>0 \\[4px]
(-x^2-6x)/10>0 \\[4px]
(-x^2-6x)/10\ne 1
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

First of all $\dfrac{-6x-x^2}{10}$ should be non-1 positive and $\sin 2x>0$ and $\sin x+\sin 3x>0$ therefore $$x^2+6x<0\\x^2+6x\ne -10$$but the latter inequality holds automatically since $\Delta<0$. Also the answers of $\sin 2x=\sin x+\sin 3x$ are$$\sin x=0\\\text{and/or}\\2\cos x=4-4\sin^2x=4\cos^2x$$therefore $$x=k\pi\\x=k\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2}\\x=2k\pi\pm\dfrac{\pi}{3}$$the only valid answer is $$x=-\dfrac{5\pi}{3}$$